# Namespace "..." does not contain any mapped entities

Tags: symfony, doctrine

when i'm trying to create entitiy from console i give this error:

Namespace "..." does not contain any mapped entities

So,

Here is my code

Which line is wrong, please tell me. Thanks.

```
                namespace SfTuts\JobeetBundle\Entity;
                use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

                /**
                * @ORM\Entity
                * @ORM\Table(name="job")
                */
                class Job
                {
                /**
                * @ORM\Id
                * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
                * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
                */
                protected $id;

                /**
                * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category")
                * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id")
                */
                protected $category;

                /**
                * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
                */
                protected $type;

                /**
                * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
                */
                protected $company;

                /**
                * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
                */
                protected $logo;

                /**
                * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
                */
                protected $url;

                /**
                * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
                */
                protected $position;

                /**
                * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
                */
                protected $location;

                /**
                * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=4000)
                */
                protected $description;

                /**
                * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=4000, name="how_to_apply")
                */
                protected $howToApply;

                /**
                * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, unique=true)
                */
                protected $token;

                /**
                * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", name="is_public")
                */
                protected $isPublic;

                /**
                * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", name="is_activated")
                */
                protected $isActivated;

                /**
                * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
                */
                protected $email;

                /**
                * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", name="created_at")
                */
                protected $createdAt;

                /**
                * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", name="updated_at")
                */
                protected $updatedAt;

                /**
                * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", name="expires_at")
                */
                protected $expiresAt;

                public function __construct()
                {
                $this->createdAt = new \DateTime();
                $this->updatedAt = new \DateTime();
                }
                }
```

How can i solve this. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
doctrine:generate:entity
```

To create a new entity.

Then after adding your own properties by editing the file, use

```
doctrine:generate:entities AcmeDemoBundle:MyEntity
```

To create getters/setters

Answer (score 0):

I found that if you change directories to the project direcotry, then add the path option to the command,it works everytime. I ran:

```
sudo app/console doctrine:generate:entities --path=./ Blog
```

while working on the symblog.dev tutorial. That's what it took to work

Answer (score 0):

I found namespace needs to match up to your entity. Double check your slashes.

`app/console doctrine:generate:entities SfTuts/JobeetBundle/Entity`

Answer (score 0):

You probably used a path instead of the namespace.

Execute the following rule:

`app/console doctrine:generate:entities SfTuts/JobeetBundle/Entity --no-backup`

Answer (score 0):

I found that this error will arise if you forgot to add your bundle to the `AppKernel` class.

After adding mine, simply using `console doctrine:generate:entities MyBundle` worked fine.